# How to convert date format in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have some date in database that date format like is `18-Dec-10`

I stored that dates in a array

```
    $my_array=array();
        $result ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'  ORDER BY date";
            $ftc = mysqli_query($conn,$result)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ftc)) {    
                    $my_array['arrays'][]  = $row['date'];
                    }
print_r(my_array);
```

i got output like `(5-Dec-11,7-Jan-12,8-Apr-10,10-May-2010)`

i can't able to get this in a order
how can i change this to sql date and how to get by order ?

Comment: What rdbms you are using?

Comment: im useing MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are storing your date as *text*, in a non standard format e.g. `18-Dec-10`.  To handle this, you may try ordering on your text dates converted to bona fide dates, using `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = '$id'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%b-%y');    -- assuming you want ascending order
```

Note that you should ideally store your date information in a proper date column, which would avoid the need to call `STR_TO_DATE`.  Working with text dates can slow you down, and be a real performance killer.

Also, as a side note, you should consider using prepared statements in your PHP code.  That is, run a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = ?
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%b-%y');
```

Then, bind the `id` value to the statement in a safe way which avoids the chance for SQL injection.

Comment: There are room for `sql` https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql